# Moving a div to another once both have been rotated

Tags: javascript, css, transform

I am trying to "swap" places with two distinct divs with some animation on a drop.

The code works fine before rotating the the some wrappers, but afterwards it is just erradic behavior.  I have read the various post on how to find the left and top after rotation , but these don't help with the animation.  [Here is a video so you can see it in action](https://youtu.be/iPSYenF_Zmc)

I know the solution is difficult because I've researched and tried all the many ways here , from getting the matrix and applying  a*x + c*y ... to jQuery hack that I've seen.  All to no avail.

Comment: Could you reproduce the problem here? You can post embedded js/css/html here

Comment: whats your exact question?

Comment: Actually I found out  that using css rotate changes the x and y axis.  So the problem was leading to unexpected outcomes with the jQuery animation.